# jQuery prevent checkbox checking nested inside another DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, click

I've looked at and tried numerous answers on this topic but can't seem to find a solution that works.  I might be missing something obvious in which case I apologise but here's my problem:

I have a checkbox nested within a DIV element, this DIV element has a jQuery click event attached to it which then checks whether the checkbox is checked or not and then either checks/unchecks it.  Depending on whether it has been checked/unchecked it then sends a variable to a PHP script to add into a session variable.

This all works fine when it's the DIV that has been clicked but when the checkbox is clicked I think some bubbling occurs as it fires the event for unchecking the checkbox every time.  I've tried using `stopPropogation();` and `preventDefault();` attached to the checkbox click event but to no avail.

Here's some sample code to try and make this clearer:

**Checkbox HTML code:**

```
<div class='bundle_offer' id='bundle_offer_0'>
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

**Click function:**

```
// Click function on bundle offer div to add booster
$(".bundle_offer").click(function (event) {

    // IF its not the checkbox clicked, send over the div id
    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {

        var bundle_offer_div_id = "#"+this.id;
        bundle_offer_click(bundle_offer_div_id);
    }
    // ELSE find div id and send it
    else{
        var bundle_offer_div_id = $(this).closest(".bundle_offer").attr("id");
        bundle_offer_div_id = "#"+bundle_offer_div_id;
        bundle_offer_click(bundle_offer_div_id);
    }
}); // end bundle offer click function
```

the `bundle_offer_click` function simply takes the id of the DIV clicked, finds the checkbox, checks/unchecks it and then sends the appropriate variable to the PHP script via AJAX.

**EDIT:**

I managed to fix the problem by moving round the logic a bit, here is what I changed it to:

```
// Click function on bundle offer div to add booster
$(".bundle_offer").mouseup(function (event) {

    // Get whether checked or not
    var isChecked = $(this).find('input').is(':checked');

    // IF its not the checkbox clicked
    // check/uncheck
    // send over the div id
    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
        if(isChecked == false){
            // Check
            $(this).find('input').attr('checked',true);
        }
        else{
            // Uncheck
            $(this).find('input').attr('checked',false);
        }
        var bundle_offer_div_id = "#"+this.id;
        bundle_offer_click(bundle_offer_div_id, isChecked);
    }

    // ELSE find div id and send it
    else{   
        var bundle_offer_div_id = $(this).closest(".bundle_offer").attr("id");
        bundle_offer_div_id = "#"+bundle_offer_div_id;
        bundle_offer_click(bundle_offer_div_id, isChecked);
    }
}); // end bundle offer click function
```

Main difference is using the `mouseup` function instead and doing the logic for checking/unchecking the checkbox within that mouseup function rather than the `bundle_offer_click` one.

Comment: Why you wrap your check box into `DIV`??Why not you just define a class or Id to your check box and catch its event???

Comment: I wrapped it into a DIV as the above code is simplified, in reality there are other things within the DIV which are then pulled into the bundle_offer_click function to pass onto the PHP script

Answer (score 0):

In case you click on check box browser automatically check/uncheck checkbox. you don't need do that using JavaScript.

I believe inside `bundle_offer_click` you are checking/unchecking checkbox. you should pass a flag as second parameter in  `bundle_offer_click` flag value should be depend on clicked element. and inside `bundle_offer_click` based on flag take action on checkbox.

code:

```
function bundle_offer_click(id, isCheckBoxClicked){
    if(isCheckBoxClicked){

       //do nothing on check box
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks a similar approach to this seemed to fix my problem, i'll update my original post with how I did it